# Why should __getattribute__ raise an AttributeError exception?

Tags: python, exception, attributes, attributeerror

The documentation on the [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) method states:

> This method should return the (computed) attribute value or raise an
>   `AttributeError` exception.

Will anything break if I raise a custom exception instead of an `AttributeError` in this method?

Comment: Because this is the proper exception for that error type.  Why would you want to return a different error?

Comment: I want to use custom exceptions for an entire class so that they can caught by caller.

Comment: Do yo have a good reason for this?  I would be really hesitant to use any library that uses custom exceptions willy-nilly for non-obvious reasons that break convention.

Comment: `__getattribute__` doesn't have to raise *specifically* an `AttributeError`; you can have it raise a *subclass* of `AttributeError`. Code that knows to look for your more specific custom exception can do so; code that only expects an `AttributeError` can still catch your custom exception without caring about its exact type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is actually just above the documentation you linked, [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) depends on the AttributeError being raised to work correctly. From the documentation of `__getattr__`:

> Called when the default attribute access fails with an AttributeError (either `__getattribute__()` raises an `AttributeError` because name is not an instance attribute or an attribute in the class tree for self; [...]

To answer the original question: You should raise either an `AttributeError` or a custom exception that inherits from `AttributeError`. Not doing so will break the standard behaviour.

Note: Depending on your use-case you may want to be using `__getattr__` instead.

Comment: You haven't answered the question.

Comment: It's really just `__getattr__` that expects it to behave that way. I'll edit the relevant documentation in for more clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't more clear—I meant the "Will anything break if I raise a custom exception...?"

Comment: Ah right, fair enough. Will add the specific answer.